# Search by meta_query

Tags: search, meta-query, date

I am building a Wordpress site with an events feature. The events page was made with custom post types.

I want to make it possible for people to search/ filter events by dates. For example, they can search for all events happening between 2nd December, 2011 and 1st March, 2012 and get results from events that have their dates between the months of December and March (ie. december, january, february and march).

I want to know the best way to go about this. Any ideas?

You can see an example of what I want to achieve by looking at the "Search events by date" feature on this page http://www.londontown.com/events

Here is the code for the start and end date meta boxes:

```
$prefix = 'ghes_';

add_filter( 'ghes_meta_boxes', 'ghes_sample_metaboxes' );

function ghes_sample_metaboxes( $meta_boxes ) {

    global $prefix;

    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'id' => 'event_meta',
        'title' => 'Event Metabox',
        'pages' => array('event'), // post type
        'context' => 'normal',
        'priority' => 'high',
        'show_names' => true,
        'fields' => array(


        array(
                'name' => 'Event Start Date',
                'desc' => 'field description (optional)',
                'id' => $prefix . 'event_start_timestamp',
                'type' => 'text_date_timestamp'
            ),

        array(
                'name' => 'Event End Date',
                'desc' => 'field description (optional)',
                'id' => $prefix . 'event_end_timestamp',
                'type' => 'text_date_timestamp'
            )
```

Here is how the date data is saved:

```
case 'text_date_timestamp':
                echo '<input class="ghes_text_small ghes_datepicker" type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? date( 'm\/d\/Y', $meta ) : $field['std'], '" /><span class="ghes_metabox_description">', $field['desc'], '</span>';
                break;
```

And this is what I have for my search box:

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get" id="searchform" class="form_search">

        Event Search:

        <!-- START Category Search -->
      <select name="event_cat">
            <option value="0">Select...</option>
            <?php
            $theterms = get_terms('event_cat', 'orderby=name');
            foreach ($theterms AS $term) :
                echo "<option value='".$term->slug."'".($_GET['event_cat'] == $term->slug ? ' selected="selected"' : '').">".$term->name."</option>\n";
            endforeach;
            ?>
        </select>

        <!-- END Category Search -->
        <!-- START Date Search -->
        <span class="em-events-search-dates">
            <?php _e('between','ghes'); ?>:

<input class="ghes_text_small ghes_datepicker" type="text_date_timestamp" name="ghes_event_start_timestamp" id="ghes_event_start_timestamp" value=""/>'
            <input type="hidden" id="ghes_event_start_timestamp" name="start" value="" />

            <?php _e('and','ghes'); ?>

<input class="ghes_text_small ghes_datepicker" type="text" name="ghes_event_end_timestamp" id="ghes_event_end_timestamp" value=""/>'
            <input type="hidden" id="ghes_event_end_timestamp" name="end" value="" />
        </span>
        <!-- END Date Search -->
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('search_events'); ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Search','ghes'); ?>" class="em-events-search-submit" />       
    </form>
```

How do I get the form to process the "date search" data and display results between the dates users select?

Is the search form missing anything? Is there something I should add to functions.php to make this work?

I have been looking for an answer for almost two weeks now and really want to learn how this works. Please share your thoughts if you have an idea of how to get this to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into meta_query:

```
$args = array(
'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'event_start_timestamp', // the name of the meta
        'value' => '11/21/2011', // the value to search for
        'compare' => '>=', //search for start dates bigger or equal to value
    )
); 
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where do I add this code; in the functions.php file or the search form? Also, should I leave the 'value' as it is (ie. 11/21/2011)? How do I get the date inputs on the search form to obey the meta_query? Please help if you can. Thanks.

Comment: On the template page you want the search to appear, I think it's index.php in your code (bloginfo('url')). You add it right before before the loop. See here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Sorry for the short answer but im working on a demo on gist.github.com for you.

Comment: Here is some code to put you in the right direction: https://gist.github.com/1464337

Comment: Thanks. I actually have a search template (search.php) to display the search results and the search form is in a template I named (custom-search.php). Obviously, I didn't point my form's action correctly.

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks. I'll let you know what happens. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, I used the code you gave me as a guide but it seems something is going wrong. The search form processes the data but no results are returned for dates I choose.

Comment: Okay I think I'm close. I have this in my search.php file now http://pastebin.com/zMRwRihz and this is what's in my search form: http://pastebin.com/nZePhPHV I am using jquery ui datepicker to select the dates in the frontend (date search input). This is what I get in the URL after submitting a search: `http://localhost/wordpress3/?s=01%2F01%2F2011&ghes_event_start_timestamp=&s=12%2F31%2F2011&ghes_event_end_timestamp=&_wpnonce=4cb83de127`  Still, no results are returned. Any clues what's preventing posts from showing? Thanks.

Comment: look at line 62 and 66 in search.php. you have the new query in `$the_query` but trying to access the result in `$events_query`.